# How do I format expressions so that replacement rules correctly apply to exponents?

Tags: output-formatting, pattern-matching, replacement

I have a series of rules that I would like to apply to a series of expressions with variables, but cannot get *Mathematica* to correctly recognize that these rules should apply when my variables have exponents in them. For example, let's suppose I know that `a b=1`.

```
a b /. a b -> 1
(* 1 *)

a c b /. a b -> 1
(* c *)
```

So those work fine. Then I try:

```
a a b /. a b -> 1
(* a^2 b *)
```

In general, my rules are a good deal more complicated, but the problem is always the same.  How do I get mathematica to recognize `a^2` as `a a` so that it correctly applies the reduction rules?

Comment: Have a look at `PolynomialReduce`. For complicated expressions that go beyond polynomials, maybe check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073530/get-mathematica-to-simplify-expression-with-another-equation)

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate since I believe the general operation you are interested in is equivalent.  Unfortunately there is not a good universal solution at this time, but see my own answer there for a collection of links to many related questions, including the one that Daniel links above.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the LHS of the replacement rule as simple as possible, e.g., use b -> 1/a

```
{a b, a b c, a a b} /. b -> 1/a
```

> {1, c, a}

Comment: How would you handle a more complex rule, for example, b^3->1 or a b->b?  These rules come from (sometimes complex) equations.  For example, I know that ab-b=0, but I have too many equations and variables for solving via cases (either b=0 or a=1) to be practical.  I also have multiple equations that affect the same variable so it's often more practical to think of b as "b" instead of "a third root of 1," although it it always more practical to think of b^3 as 1.

Comment: `Simplify[a b^5, b^3 == 1]` gives `a b^2`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`HoldForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html) for this:

```
HoldForm[a a b] /. a b -> 1
(* a 1 *)
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, by the time that I am ready to apply replacement rules, Mathematica has already auto-formatted my expression.  How do I get it back into the form a a b?

Comment: @Susan Maybe you can use `HoldForm` somewhere earlier? I currently don't think of any way to convert `a^2` to `a a`.

Comment: I am fairly confident that I cannot.  I heavily rely on Mathematica to make simplifications first.  For example, I usually need to get a common denominator, cancel, and then extract the numerator.  I also evaluate some of my variables as I discover their values (although not all variables will have values).  It doesn't seem like Mathematica should have such a hard time applying a rule for products to an expression that it knew was a product prior to autoformatting?